# Hive query taking long time to start MR job

Tags: hive

I am querying hive table which contains around 10m rows. earlier query use to finish quickly on hive 0.14. Then I moved to hive 1.2.1 and now its not starting MR job

```
hive> select count(1) from nodes;
Query ID = lagvankarh_20160608221653_5dd82f87-3527-4eb6-9a59-f11ccaf0a125
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
```

I get SocketTimeout error after long time.

Comment: Is this the first query after upgradation?

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to check count

Comment: There can be some installation problem .Please try to install once again...